# "The remote server returned an error: (404) NOT FOUND"

Tags: c#, wcf, service, http-status-code-404

Firstly, describe structure.

My solution contains:

1. WCF service project (with connection to DB via EF)
2. Windows Service  project - host for WCF service
3. Client application (has Service references to WCF service)

Client's service reference has name - SCS. WCF Service name - ControllerService.
So, in the login view (Client app) I wrote :

```
client = new SCS.ControllerServiceClient();
```

and it's working well.

But, I have a requirement: client application must have a feature to change connection to service via change server name and port.

So, I must write something like this:

```
client = new SCS.ControllerServiceClient(ConfigurationEndpointName, Endpoint);
```

but it doesn't work and throws an exception

> The remote server returned an error: (404) NOT FOUND

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the web.config or app.config in your client app do you have the specified configurationendpoint defined.

Comment: I'd say you've got the wrong address in your endpoint.

Comment: with endpoint everything is OK! app.config has specified configurationendpoint defined(in my example is ConfigurationEndpointName)

Comment: Does that line throw the exception or does it occur on the first line that calls a method on the service?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".